# Are there fewer firmware chips in a mobile device compared with a laptop or a desktop?

Tags: mobile, hardware, firmware

For a conventional laptop or desktop computer, there appear to be many firmware chips in which malware might hide:

- internal drives
- network card
- graphics card
- sound card
- embedded controller
- BIOS firmware chip
- VDU firmware chip(s)
- etc.

I was wondering whether it might be the case that mobile devices, *in contrast*, generally only have one firmware chip in which malware might hide. Does anyone know?

#### Background

I am looking at processes where all firmware chips are faithfully <sup>re-installed</sup>／<sub>re-imaged</sub> so as to get rid of all potential firmware malware.

Comment: Although you are asking about places for malware to hide, this isn't about malware or security. Just mobile hardware design.

Comment: Today we have SoCs combining many of these in a single chip

Comment: I don't know about fewer, but "only have one firmware chip" is definitely wrong. It may be a single piece of silicon, but inside it are many different processors that each have their independent firmware.

Comment: Counting physical chips makes little sense when an eeprom ic might have a single firmware while a SOC might have dozens flashes to different internal memories. You need to look at the underlying manuals for the respective devices to see which has more.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a cautious "yes", simply because the BOM is smaller - there are fewer functions, so there are fewer chips, and they're all on one board, and they don't need to be pluggable or standalone.

The place to look is [teardowns such as iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+12+and+12+Pro+Teardown/137669) that enumerate the chips. However, you still need to check if each package contains multiple dies, one of which may be internal Flash for more firmware.

Subsidiary chips may contain firmware in mask ROM, but since this is unchangeable it's not of security interest.